# Wordpress scales full sized image instead of serving thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

My thumbnail settings are currently: 150x150 (thumbnail), 824x824 (medium), 1024x1024 (large)

When an archive is displayed, the thumbnails used for each post are actually the full sized image but scaled to 375x250. You'll see that if you inspect any image, thumbnails of various sizes do exist yet WP ignores them and loads the full sized image instead.

Also, the code that loads the image is simply:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

Why is this happening? How do make it load the thumbnail instead?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc [post-thumbnails](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/)

Did you enable it in your function.php inside

```
function yourThemeName_setup() {
...

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

...
}
```

Another option is passing the size as an argument like

```
the_post_thumbnail( array( 150, 150 ) ); // Resolutions (height, width)
```

if not you can achieve this by creating a custom_size inside the function.php

```
add_image_size( 'custom_post-thumbnail', 150, 150 );
```

and then use it

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'custom_post-thumbnail' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Shouldn't WP be automatically using the created thumbs instead of scaling the full size images? I feel like there must be some reason this started happening in the first place.

Comment: There's (as often happens with WordPress) some confusing terminology. The 'post_thumbnail' is the featured image for the post. It needn't be thumbnail-sized. Historically, it had to be, hence the assumption in the terminology. Since WordPress is reluctant to change the names of things, even if they no longer make sense, you end up with seemingly redundant calls like `the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' )`. But consider using ` set_post_thumbnail_size()`.